# Provision developer environment with chef server and vagrant without registering node

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo, berkshelf

I wish to create a developer environment of a web based application which will have an application server and database server installed on a VM using vagrant. I am using open source chef server and vagrant with `chef_client` provisioner. However each time a developer node is provisioned, `chef_client` provisioner creates a client node on chef server. This is not desirable because this setup will be used by a lot of developers. Such nodes might get created and destroyed several times. So maintaining the list of such nodes on chef server is not required.

`chef_solo` is another option but it requires the cookbook to be present in the system. We are using chef server as a repository for cookbooks as well. So a developer need not have the specific cookbook in his/her system. I have looked at berkshelf as well where I can configure `chef_api` path to the chef server. But that too requires a node. Following is my vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise64-chef"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.10"
  config.omnibus.chef_version = '11.8.2'
  config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
    chef.log_level = :debug
    chef.environment = "development"
    chef.delete_node = true
    chef.delete_client = true
    chef.node_name = "sample_app"
    chef.chef_server_url = "https://chef-server-url"
    chef.validation_key_path = "chef-validator.pem"
    chef.add_role "base"
    chef.add_role "pg_client"
    chef.add_role "application_server"
    chef.add_role "db_server"
    chef.add_recipe "deploy_application"
  end
end
```

I wish to not create `sample_app` node on chef server. Otherwise this serves my purpose. Any other strategies to provision developer environment using chef server are welcome.

Answer (score 10):

## Immediate solution

### Butcher plugin

The immediate answer that springs to mind is use the [vagrant butcher](https://github.com/cassianoleal/vagrant-butcher) plugin. This will automtically delete your developer client and node entries on the chef server.

## Longer term solution

Since you're aware of the Berkshelf ["chef_api" directive](http://berkshelf.com/#chef_api_location) I will assume you have the typical Enterprise scenario where several developers are sharing locally developed cookbooks.

Here's what I'm doing with chef....

### Chef cookbook repository pattern

Reserve an instance of chef server as a repository of cookbooks. Each released cookbook version is pushed here and made available for consumption by all internal users of chef.

To maintain the repository cookbooks, use Jenkins to implement a CI process for cookbooks. Jenkins jobs pull from local GIT repositories, or from the community cookbook site. The advantage of this approach is that tests can be automated using [chef spec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec) and QA rules can be implemented using tools like [foodcritic](http://www.foodcritic.io/). In this manner build failures help improve the overall quality of the cookbooks in use within the organisation.

I reckon this repository pattern is something we're going to a lot more of when the Berkshelf guys finally launch [Berkshelf 3.0](http://prezi.com/knlq4ojxbk_c/berkshelf-30/) (See also [berkshelf-api](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api)).

### Use Berkshelf to load cookbooks

Berkshelf is used to control the loading of cookbooks into all chef servers (dev or prod). The following is a demo "Berksfile":

```
chef_api "https://cookbook.repo.myorg.com/", node_name: "dev1", client_key: "/path/to/dev1/private/key/key.pem"

cookbook "apache2"
cookbook "mysql"
...
```

The "chef_api" directive tells berkshelf to load all cookbooks from the local chef cookbook repository, instead of defaulting to loading from the community repository.

This makes it trivial to create "production-like" copies of your main chef server. It also enables one of the more magical aspects of berkshelf. Each cookbook in your system can have it's own simple Berksfile:

```
chef_api "https://cookbook.repo.myorg.com/".....

metadata
```

The "metadata" statement tells Berkshelf to load the cookbooks listed as dependencies in the cookbook's metadata file. This is wonderful, a simple "berks upload" and all the cookbooks I need get automatically loaded into my development chef server.

### Use Spiceweasel for loading chef server

Very useful tool. Integrates Berkshelf and generates all the other knife commands for loading a chef server from a [chef repository](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_repository.html).

https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel

### Development: Chef Zero and Vagrant

Once cookbooks are under control (using Berkshelf) my advise is to adopt [Chef zero](https://github.com/opscode/chef-zero). Each developer can then have their own locally managed chef server instance.

Here are the vagrant plugins I routinely install to support chef cookbook development:

- [Omnibus plugin](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) : Ensures I'm running a specified version of chef-client
- [Berkshelf plugin](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf) : Downloads and manages my cookbooks
- [Chef zero plugin](https://github.com/andrewgross/vagrant-chef-zero) : Runs a local copy of chef server

Once a cookbook is ready, it gets committed and pushed. Jenkins will then pick up the new revision and automatically loads it into the cookbook repository.

Comment: This is really helpful. I will mark this answer as accepted once I try this methodology. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For me the developers are java developers who are do not maintain chef cookbooks. They will not have the chef repo on their systems but would do local deployments using chef. Is it possible with `chef_client` to not register node with chef server in the first place? Since I am using roles to define a run list, berkshelf might not be useful here. We wish to streamline local deployments with chef. Is it a correct use case?

Comment: I don't think so. Chef client entities are created by the initial registeration that each client must do with chef server. The node data is created at the end of the chef run and is basically a dump of the node object created during the chef run. Seems to me the best approach to consider is using the chef-zero plugin for vagrant. That way each chef server instance runs locally and just rely on Berkshelf to keep the cookbooks syn'ed. Stuff like roles can also be kept in the git repo and loaded by chef zero. Try it out!