# Managing custom cookbooks in a chef repo

Tags: chef-infra

I was wondering how Chef users organize custom cookbooks with relation to the main Chef repository. I started a repository based on a blank [Chef Repo](https://github.com/opscode/chef-repo), and then installed custom cookbooks into the chef repo (i.e. the cookbook code is managed in the chef repo codebase). It's becoming a bit unmanageable though - especially when we want to work on different versions of a cookbook, and I'm wondering if it makes more sense to create independent cookbook projects and then pull in the cookbooks with Berkshelf - what's recommended in terms of best practises and how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping cookbooks in a GIT [chef repository](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_repository.html) doesn't scale well. I keep my cookbooks in an instance of Chef server, acting as a cookbook repository (I don't connect VMs to this chef server). It is designed to fulfil the same purpose as [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) (or [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview)) in Java development, a place to hold my development dependencies.

When loading a new chef server I download my cookbook's dependencies using Berkshelf, referencing this chef server using an "chef_api" directive:

- [Provision developer environment with chef server and vagrant without registering node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280706/provision-developer-environment-with-chef-server-and-vagrant-without-registering/22283678#22283678)

This will all change with Berkshelf 3.0 (Just released). I want to check out [berkshelf-api](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf-api) which I'm hoping will simplify my work-flow. Reportedly Berkshelf-api can serve up cookbooks from:

- Community cookbook site
- An instance of chef server (like I do)
- Cookbooks stored on file-system (This might suit you better)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It did help. To clarify how I've been using Chef with VCS: The full chef repo, including custom cookbooks, is in a git repo. Our CI does a pull and uploads to a chef server using knife.

I was wondering what benefits there'd be to maintaining my cookbooks (that are private, and will probably stay that way) into their own repos though and reference them with Berkshelf with a git resource locator, instead of managing the cookbooks within the main chef repo. I currently have 4 or 5 custom, private cookbooks.

Comment: @Brett Your workflow is the one that was originally followed by all chef developers. It works fine for a small number of cookbooks. The best practice of breaking cookbooks out into separate repos and using Berkshelf to manage dependencies emerged later to cope with scaling. As you cookbooks increase, keeping them in-sync with upstream community changes becomes harder and harder. Finally it's worth using the community cookbooks. Their quality is very high and you learn stuff by reading them.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. I use community cookbooks was much as possible, and contribute towards them too. The custom cookbooks are for internal applications only.

Comment: @Brett Just occured to me. It's possible to reference cookbooks stored locally from a Berkshelf file. See the "path" attribute of the "cookbook" directive in the Berksfile. This enables the best of both worlds.